# Set DNS settings on Windows 10 Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: powershell, dns, windows-10, raspberry-pi2

I try to set DNS settings on windows 10, raspberry pi 2 using Powershell:

```powershell
Set-DNSClientServerAddress –InterfaceIndex <number> -ServerAddresses DNS1-IP,DNS2-IP
```

But I receive the following error:

> The term 'Set-DNSClientServerAddress' is not recognized as the name of
>   a cmdlet CommandNotFoundException

How can you succeed the DNS settings?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't tryed the IoT Version of Windows 10 yet but maybe the Powershell cmdlets are limited?

However, you could also try to set the DNS [using the Get-WmiObject cmdlet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176860.aspx):

```powershell
$wmi = Get-WmiObject win32_networkadapterconfiguration -filter "ipenabled = 'true'"
$wmi.SetDNSServerSearchOrder('DNS1-IP','DNS2-IP')
```